# can't DROP COLUMN - MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table, drop

I just created a new table and I want to remove the '`person`' column in it but I get an error -

```
CREATE TABLE new_info(
info_id INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
person VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

And after this -

```
ALTER TABLE new_info
DROP COLUMN person;
```

I get this error  -

```
Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'UQ__informat__DC4560C2776204D1' is dependent on column 'person'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN person failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

Any Idea why, or what's causing this ?

Comment: You need to drop the unique constraint first, and then the column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried I get: `'person' is not a constraint.`

Comment: `UQ__informat__DC4560C2776204D1` is a constraint you need to remove first

Comment: @GuidoG Thank you. And thats really very complicated to know whats the code before I actually get this error.

Comment: The reason it looks "complicated" is because you didn't name your `CONSTRAINT`, @Ileh . It's good habit to name them, so that you don't get "unfriendly" names like that for your objects.

Answer (score 2):

Drop the unique constraint first before you can drop the column
This is why it is always best to create named constraint

```
ALTER TABLE new_info DROP CONSTRAINT UQ__informat__DC4560C2776204D1
```

and then you can drop your column.
You can also do it in one statement, as commented by Martin

```
ALTER TABLE new_info DROP UQ__informat__DC4560C2776204D1, 
                          COLUMN person
```

Better to create tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE new_info(
  info_id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  title VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  person VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

 constraint PK_new_info_InfoID primary key (info_id),
 constraint IX_new_info_person UNIQUE (person)
)
```

now you will at least get better info in your errormessages

Comment: It doesn't need to be a separate statement `ALTER TABLE new_info
DROP UQ__informat__DC4560C2776204D1 , COLUMN person;` would also work